# Invalid Hook Call for Button to submit form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a button that is supposed to submit a form to an API. I am getting an error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function...
```

My entire code is here:

```
function SubmitButton(props) {
  function SendData(url) {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const eta = document.getElementById('eta_value')
    async function getData() {
      const options ={
          method : 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            name:'26',
            eta:'30',
          })
      }
      const response = await fetch(url, options)
          .then(response =>{
              console.log(response.status);
          });
    }
    useEffect(() => {//check this out
      getData();
    }, []);
  };
  const title = props.title;
  //const onSubmit = {SendData}
  return(
      <div id={title}>
        <Button 
        onClick={() => SendData("http://XXX.X.X.X:XXXX/api/")} 
        variant="contained" 
        color="primary">
        </Button>
      </div>
  )
}
export default SubmitButton
```

It shows the error originates at:

```
function SendData(url) {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const eta = document.getElementById('eta_value')
    async function getData() {
```

Which is called by onClick.
I troubleshooted for several days, but cannot figure out why I am breaking the rules of hooks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `useState` hook within a nested function (your `sendData()` function).

As the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) documentation reads:

> Only Call Hooks at the Top Level
>
> Don’t call Hooks inside loops,
>   conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top
>   level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that
>   Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.
>   That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks
>   between multiple useState and useEffect calls. (If you’re curious,
>   we’ll explain this in depth below.)

To fix this, move your `const [data, setData] = useState([]);` statement and the `useEffect()` hook to the top level of your functional component.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The useEffect needs to be pulled out to the top-level as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your hooks calls must be on the top level of your render function([react hook rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)), not inside of SendData function

```
function SubmitButton(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]); 
  function SendData(url) {
    const eta = document.getElementById('eta_value')
    async function getData() {
      const options ={
          method : 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            name:'26',
            eta:'30',
          })
      }
      const response = await fetch(url, options)
          .then(response =>{
              console.log(response.status);
          });
    }  
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
  const title = props.title;
  //const onSubmit = {SendData}
  return(
      <div id={title}>
        <Button 
        onClick={() => SendData("http://XXX.X.X.X:XXXX/api/")} 
        variant="contained" 
        color="primary">
        </Button>
      </div>
  )
}
export default SubmitButton
```

And you'd better move code that fetches data outside of render function, for the sake of readability, hope it helped :)

Comment: Thank you. It fixes that problem but now useEffect is trying to call getData before getData is defined